# (Any / No) + singular or plural noun

Tags: grammar

I was wondering whether after "no" and "any" one must use a noun in a plural or singular form.

**Example:**

> **1.** She has **no** emotional **attachment** with her family. 
> **2.** She has **no** emotional **attachments** with her family. 
> **3.** She doesn't have **any** emotional **attachment** with her family. 
> **4.** She doesn't have **any** emotional **attachments** with her family.

To me, singular form is more preferable in either case, but I don't have a clue if I am right grammatically.

Comment: Can you say what multiple "emotional attachments" would be with one entity (her family)? I don't see it, both "she" and "family" are singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the object countable? The following would all be correct.

- For countable nouns:

  Yes, we have no bananas.

  There aren't any bananas.
- For uncountable nouns:

  We have no ice cream.

  There isn't any ice cream.

However, "There **aren't** any ice cream **bars**," because an ice cream bar is discrete. Enjoy it discreetly.